# daterangepicker が複数ある場合の個別処理の方法

Tags: javascript, jquery

以下を使っています。
http://www.daterangepicker.com/

同ページ内に日付入力欄が複数あるため(動的にいくつでも作成されます)、セレクタは `$('.daterange')` といった形でクラス指定しています。

日付入力欄それぞれにつき値の表示を変更する処理をcallback関数で行いたいのですが、callback関数内では this が使えず、以下のコードでは値が変更されません。
どのように改善すれば、値を変更した欄のみ値の表示を変更できるようになりますでしょうか。
ご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
  function cb(start, end) {
      console.log(start.unix());
      if(start.unix()==moment.utc(0).unix()){
          $(this).val("ALL"); //<-thisが使えないため動かない
          //$(".daterange span").html("ALL"); <-全ての値が変わってしまう
      }else{
          $(this).val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm Z') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm Z'));
      }
  }

  $('.daterange').daterangepicker({
      timePicker: true,
      autoUpdateInput: false
  }, cb);
```

Comment: `autoUpdateInput: false`下の波カッコ閉じはtypoですよね??

Comment: typoでした、失礼致しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

daterangepickerを使うのは初めてですが、ちょとスニペット作ってみました。
試してみたところ、callback内で`this.element`が使えそうです。

```js
function callback(start, end) {
  // this.element === 変更対象のDOM
  console.log($(this.element).attr('name'));
  console.log($(this.element).val());
}

$('.daterange').daterangepicker({
  timePicker: true,
  autoUpdateInput: false
}, callback);
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" name="range1" class="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

<input type="text" name="range2" class="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
```

Comment: $(this.element) で取得できました！本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: よく見たら題名でもtypoしておりました、拙い質問にも関わらず素早くご回答くださり、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決の兆しが見えたようで何よりです!!